# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float android.view.InputDevice$MotionRange.getMin()'

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, flutter

I receive the error below every time I click in a Widget :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float android.view.InputDevice$MotionRange.getMin()' on a null object reference
```

I change to another project and receive the same error, the error happens with a TextField, a button and a item of GridList.

I think that can be a error in a sdk

```
Flutter: 1.2.1
Dart: 2.2.0
```

I upgraded my flutter and receiving this now.
The complete log is it:

```
 Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime(26099): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099): Process: videira.com.videiralideres, PID:
 26099 E/AndroidRuntime(26099): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt
 to invoke virtual method 'float
 android.view.InputDevice$MotionRange.getMin()' on a null object
 reference E/AndroidRuntime(26099):     at
 io.flutter.view.FlutterView.addPointerForIndex(FlutterView.java:480)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
 io.flutter.view.FlutterView.onTouchEvent(FlutterView.java:542)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
 android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11779)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2971)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2600)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2971)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2600)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2971)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2600)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
 com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:477)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
 com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1835)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
 android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3326)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
 com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:439)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
 android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12018)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
 android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4829)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
 android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4643)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
 android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
 E/AndroidRuntime(26099):   at
```

**New Detail:**
I can see that error happens when I use a mirror (Vysor or ScrCpy), I just can use the app when I use the real phone with my fingers.

Comment: Probably this is the PR to fix it: https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/7986

Comment: What is PR? Sorry that I don't know

Comment: I mean it is flutter bug, you can get flutter latest code to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Bug in flutter when we use a app to mirror in the PC, just need to update the Flutter, I'm using the 1.3.8 and work fine.